# Rails background image not show?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

In my rails app file: `application.scss`, I set like following: (I want `backtest.png` shows in any page.)

```
body 
  {
    background-image: image-url("backtest.png");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y; 

    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

and in `login.html.erb`, I want to show another image:

```
body {
      background-image: url('/assets/iot.png');
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
```

at local side, I use rails server to display, and it's fine, but when I upload to Nginx, the `backtest.png` still OK, but `iot.png` doesn't show, even not show `backtest.png`, just a white color background? How can I fix that?

I had do `assets:clean`, `assets:precompile` ever when I push new version.

config/deploy/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

tried both change to `background-image: url`, and two images not show, tried `background-image: url('/assets/iot.png');` to `image-url`, but it not work on `.erb`.

Comment: Its url not image-url.

Comment: you have used `background-image: image-url("backtest.png");`  replace `image-url` with `url`

Comment: I tried, at local , it's works, but in Nginx production, two images not show! It just white background, why?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal This is a Ruby on Rails application, `image-url()` is an asset helper for Sass that gets compiled to `url()`.

Comment: but I can't use background-image: image-url in login.html.erb, just can use background-image: url, how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `asset_path` helper as a ruby injection in your `login.html.erb`:

```
background-image: url('<%= asset_path 'iot.png' %>');
```